# Searching for a row in the database doesn't work, String comparison error

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to make a register-login app in android studio and I've come across some problems in the registration part. This is my code in `RegisterActivity`:

```
public void addUser (View view) {
    StringBuffer errors = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer noerrors = new StringBuffer();
    errors.append("");
    noerrors.append("");

    String firstname = FirstName.getText().toString();
    String lastname = LastName.getText().toString();
    String username = UserName.getText().toString();
    String password = UserPassoword.getText().toString();
    String retypepassword = RetypePassword.getText().toString();
    String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();

    if(!searchUsername(username)) {
        errors.append("Username already exists\n");
        UserName.clearComposingText();

    }

    if(!searchEmail(email)) {
        errors.append("Email already in use\n");
        UserEmail.clearComposingText();
    }

    if(password.equals(retypepassword)){
        errors.append("Password retyped incorrectly");
        UserPassoword.clearComposingText();
        RetypePassword.clearComposingText();
    }

    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    if(errors.toString().equals(noerrors.toString())) {
        userDbHelper.addInformation(firstname, lastname, username, password, email, sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Register successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, errors, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    userDbHelper.close();
}

public boolean searchUsername(String username) {

    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = userDbHelper.getUsername(username, sqLiteDatabase);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my database helper

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USERINFO.DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
            "CREATE TABLE " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + UserContract.NewUserInfo.FIRST_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    UserContract.NewUserInfo.LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL + " TEXT);";

    public UserDbHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    }

    public void addInformation (String firstname, String lastname, String username, String password, String email, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.FIRST_NAME, firstname);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.LAST_NAME, lastname);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, username);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);

        db.insert(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "One row inserted");
    }

    public Cursor getUsername (String username, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.FIRST_NAME, UserContract.NewUserInfo.LAST_NAME,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        String selection = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args = {username};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

In my registration form, whenever I retype the password correctly, my stringbuffer shows "Password retyped incorrectly" and when I retype it incorrectly, this message doesn't appear.

In the database helper, the searchEmail method is the same as searchUsername, only with a few changes so that it seaches for the email. Whether I type a username/email that is or isn't in the database, "Username already exists" and "Email already in use" are appended.

I also don't get why .clearComposingText() doesn't work to clear my edittext fields.

Comment: To clear text, use `EditText`'s `setText()` method to simply set the text to `""`

Comment: @BVB: I thought about that, as well, but I hoped that by calling that method, I'd get the same result. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You're missing a '!' before if(password.equals(retypepassword)){ as written if you retype the password correctly you show a message that you typed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The two methods, `searchEmail` and `searchUsername`, need to take the View object as a parameter.